# Complete page html via c# or jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Is there a way with Asp.net, Jquery and Ajax to capture the current pages html and email or save it.  I have a page with a dynamically generated amount of inputs, and there are quite a few.  What I'd like to do is just capture the complete html of the form after it's filled out and email it.  Is there a way to do this.  I have a webservice, and it's passing in the data via ajax, but it's having a problem handling the greater than and less than symbols and quotes ect.  The point is to have a nice readable copy of whatever they type in the screen.  An html email is the way the customer wants to go.  Thanks!

This could also be directly in the code behind, but i can't find a way to do that server side with the client not posting back.

The error i receive in firebug is "Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected.

Answer (score 0):

> it's having a problem handling the greater than and less than symbols
>   and quotes ect.

You should try [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) in order to fix that problem.

For the rest, you should try this ([source](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t72582-using-webrequest-to-get-the-rendered-html-of-protected-page-returns-login-page.html)):

```
private void SaveWebPage_as_HTML()
{
    // Initialize the WebRequest.
    string urlToConvert = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url).ToStr ing();
    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlToConvert);
    // Return the response. 
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

    // Obtain a 'Stream' object associated with the response object.
    Stream ReceiveStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

    // Pipe the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode, true, 255);

    // Read 256 charcters at a time. 
    Char[] read = new Char[256];
    int count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.html"))
    {
        while (count > 0)
        {
        // Dump the 256 characters on a string and display the string onto the console.
        String str = new String(read, 0, count);
        sw.Write(str);
        count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }
    }

    // Close the response to free resources.
    myResponse.Close();
}
```

Pay close attention to the Encoding used (here it is utf-8) as this might cause "readability" issues.